# Required api's for crypto token wallet

Tags: web3js, wallets, tokens, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I am creating the api server for creating the interaction with crypto token smart contract , i want to know the required api's through which i can perform basic functionality of sending and receiving the tokens. And please suggest the required security measures for the api server .

Tech used for api server - node.js

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use web3.js for writing such api's. I have written sample api's which may help you. Have a look at [Blockchain api](https://github.com/prashantprabhakar/EthereumBlockchainApi). These api's were written just for information, this is just a sample. You can fork and customize it for your purpose.

You need to add security constraints and exception handling. I'll update the api's soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the web3js directly without any third-party API. please read the instructions to install and use it for nodejs : 
https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/

concerning the security for the smart contract you can start with the consensus [best practices](https://github.com/ConsenSys/smart-contract-best-practices), and for the nodejs you will find on the web many [guides](http://nodewebapps.com/2017/01/03/13-security-best-practices-for-your-web-application/) to secure your server and code.

Comment: i already wrote the smart contracts , and i know about the web3.js . I just want to know the no. of api's and list of them that fulfill the requirement of  crypto token transfer , balance check , transaction history etc . For the security check i want to know the list of security features that should be implemented for and blockchain wallet api server

Answer (score 0):

You could do a token  payment processor using web3.js only.

In your case, I would make a frontend where user can interact with the API and their own wallets, then the API endpoint itself in node.js.

Example: for checking if transaction done, I would check if X correct amount was really sent from X to X.

Really web3.js (https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/) is the key, maybe  also take a look at zero provider (https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3-provider-engine)  or ethutils.js (https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-util)